# Learning Python Parsers

Tags: python, matlab, parsing, python-3.2

I'm fairly new to Python and trying to set up a class with a constructor to have a small number of required properties and a larger number of optional ones with defaults and definitions of acceptable inputs.

I've tried using the argparse module, but I am not understanding how to parse the arguments then pass the results into the properties of the class. This also has not allowed me to define logical criteria for expected inputs.

I'm looking to do something similar to this MATLAB script.

```
methods
        function obj = Platform(ClassID,varargin)
            inPar = inputParser;
            
            expectedClass = {'Ownship', 'Wingman', 'Flight Group', 'Unknown', 'Suspect', 'Neutral', 'Friend', 'Foe'};
            validClassID = @(x) any(validatestring(x,expectedClass));
            addRequired(inPar,'ClassID',validClassID)
            
            defaultDim = struct('length', 0, 'width', 0, 'height', 0, 'oOffset', [0 0 0]);
            validDim = @(x) ~isempty(intersect(fieldnames(x),fieldnames(defaultDim)));
            addOptional(inPar,'Dimensions',defaultDim,validDim)
            
            defaultPos = [0 0 0];
            validPos = @(x) isclass(x,'double') && mean(size(x) == [1 3]);
            addOptional(inPar,'Position',defaultPos,validPos)
            
            defaultOr = [0 0 0];
            validOr = @(x) isclass(x,'double') && mean(size(x) == [1 3]);
            addOptional(inPar,'Orientation',defaultOr,validOr)
          
            defaultTraj = struct('Waypoints',[0 0 0],...
                'TimeofArrival',0,...
                'Velocity',[0 0 0],...
                'Orientation',[0 0 0]);
            validTraj = @(x) ~isempty(fieldnames(x),fieldnames(defaultTraj));
            addOptional(inPar,'Trajectory',defaultTraj,validTraj)
            
            expectedDL = {'One','Two','Three};
            defaultDL = {};
            validDL = @(x) any(validatestring(x,expectedDL));
            addOptional(inPar,'DataLinks',defaultDL,validDL)
            
            defaultSens = {};
            validSens = @(x) isa(x,'Sensor');
            addOptional(inPar,'Sensors',defaultSens,validSens)
            
            
            parse(inPar,ClassID,varargin{:})
            
            obj.PlatformID = randi([1 10000]);
            obj.ClassID = inPar.Results.ClassID;
            obj.Dimensions = inPar.Results.Dimensions;
            obj.Position = inPar.Results.Position;
            obj.Orientation = inPar.Results.Orientation;
            obj.Trajectory = inPar.Results.Trajectory;            
            obj.Sensors = inPar.Results.Sensors;
            obj.DataLinks = inPar.Results.DataLinks;

            
        end
```

Comment: What do you have so far?  argparse does a certain amount of validation, but you will have to follow up with some of your own.

Comment: Actually, let me back up.  Are you trying to valid parameters passed to a function, or are you trying to validate parameters from the command line?  `argparse` is used for command-line arguments.  Python doesn't have any capabilities for bulk validation of function parameters.

Comment: This isn't how python "works" in most senses. The constructor for the class is where you would define the defaults and you'd take the user input to override them, if they are passed

Comment: In other words, the class could almost "stand alone" if you created an instance of it, and you are responsible for the validation step in between the user input and the instance

Comment: Python has much more powerful abstractions and programming tools available than MATLAB. A good Python analog would break this monolithic class down into smaller, independent objects that manage their own invariants instead of having one class that does it all. For example, `Position` and `Orientation` could be their own classes (probably named tuples or dataclasses), `ClassID` should probably either be an enum or expressed via inheritance, etc.

Comment: @Brian61354270 in the MATLAB script, those are all independent classes too, but they are intended to be descriptors of each object of the 'Platform' class, that's why the 'isa' command works.

I'd like to make all of those descriptors be accessible under the one object, if that makes sense.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm intending to use this "stand alone" as a way to make sure that all properties of the class used by any of its methods exist in the right format to prevent errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happily, Python has no need of doing this sort of ad-hoc string and array parsing.

Good Python code is *object oriented*.  Instead of passing values around as raw strings and arrays, you should encapsulate them into *objects of meaningful types*. Those objects should be left responsible for validating themselves when constructed and for maintaining their invariants throughout their lifetime.

Even better Python code can take advantage of static type hinting to offload much of that validation to before your code is even run.

An idiomatic Python translation might look something like this (with some liberal guesswork interpretation):

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import NamedTuple, Literal

class Position(NamedTuple):
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float

    @classmethod
    def origin(cls) -> Position:
        return cls(0, 0, 0)

class Orientation(NamedTuple):
    yaw: float
    pitch: float
    roll: float

    @classmethod
    def pos_x(cls) -> Orientation:
        return cls(0, 0, 0)

    @classmethod
    def pos_y(cls) -> Orientation:
        return cls(1, 0, 0)

    @classmethod
    def pos_z(cls) -> Orientation:
        return cls(0, 1, 0)

class Geometry(NamedTuple):
    extent: Position
    o_offset: Position

    @classmethod
    def unit_cube(cls) -> Geometry:
        return cls((1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0))

@dataclass
class Trajectory:
    waypoints: list[Position] = field(default_factory=list)
    time_of_arrival: float = 0
    velocity: Position = Position.origin()
    orientation: Orientation = Orientation.pos_x()

class Platform(ABC):

    _geometry: Geometry
    _position: Position
    _orientation: Orientation
    _trajectory: Trajectory
    _datalinks: list[Literal['One','Two','Three']]
    _sensors: list[Sensors]

    def __init__(
        self,
        geometry: Geometry = Geometry.unit_cube(),
        pos: Position = Position.origin(),
        orientation: Orientation = Orientation.pos_x(),
        trajectory: Trajectory | None = None,
        datalinks: list[Literal['One','Two','Three'] | None = None,
        sensors: list[Sensors] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        if trajectory is None:
            trajectory = Trajectory()

        if datalinks is None:
            datalinks = []

        if sensors is None:
            sensors =  []

        self._geometry = geometry
        self._position = pos
        self._orientation = orientation
        self._trajectory = trajectory
        self._datalinks = datalinks
        self._sensors = sensors

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something_class_specific(self) -> None:
        ...

class NeutralPlatform(Platform):
    def do_something_class_specific(self) -> None:
        self.watch_and_wait()

class FooPlatform(Platform):
    def do_something_class_specific(self) -> None:
        self.attack_mode()
```

That's it! Any `Platform`s you construct will be fully validated, provided type checking passes. No need implement manual validation for things that the type system can already verify!

Need more invariants? Enforce them in the appropriate type. In a good object oriented design, `Platform` does not (and should not) need to know anything about what makes a valid `Orientation`, only that it has one and that it's already valid.

Comment: “Good Python code is object oriented.” This is an opinion, not a fact. And you can do exactly the same thing in MATLAB if you like. Neither Python nor MATLAB check the type of its input arguments, you have to do this explicitly. Static type checking works only if you put in the additional effort to set it up. Using this class from, say, a Jupiter notebook would leave it without any form of input argument checking.